# HTML5/jQuery Mobile: how do I add a data id to a list item?

Tags: jquery, html, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I have an unordered list consisting of items to which rows of data from an HTML5 web database have been appended. 
I am trying to add each row's id to its respective list item, in order to be able to delete each item by its id.
When I try to delete an item, regardless of which one I select, the last item added is the one that gets deleted. 
Also, I can only delete one item at a time before having to refresh the page.

My code thus far is as follows:

```
function refreshEntries() {
db.transaction(
    function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql(  
        'SELECT * FROM eyeshadowEntries', [],
            function (tx, result) {
                $("#eyeshadow ul").html("");
                for (var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = result.rows.item(i);
                    var brand = $("<li>"+row.brand+", "+row.productName+", "+row.shade+", "+row.datePurchased+"</li>");
                    brand.data("entryId", row.id).addClass(row.id);
                    var deleteElem = $("<span></span>").addClass("delete").text("Delete");
                    deleteElem.appendTo(brand);
                    var brandLi = brand.appendTo("#eyeshadow ul");
                    brandLi.find(".delete").click(function(){
                        var clickedEntryId = brandLi.data("entryId");
                        deleteEntryById(clickedEntryId);
                        brandLi.remove();

                    });

                }
            },      
            errorHandler
        );
    }
);
}

function deleteEntryById(id) {
db.transaction(
    function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('DELETE FROM eyeshadowEntries WHERE id=?;', [id], null, errorHandler);
    }
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

m not very familiar with HTML5, but as far as I can see, u have named the data entryID
it should probably  be

```
 transaction.executeSql('DELETE FROM eyeshadowEntries WHERE id=?;', [entryId], null, errorHandler);
```

I can't be sure though, cuz as I said m not familiar with HTML5

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately got the following error message:   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: entryId

Comment: Upon further examination, I think the problem lies within the following line:  `brand.data("entryId", row.id).addClass(row.id);`  The row id does not appear to be getting added.